# How to beautify JavaScript files recursively?

Tags: command-line, files, javascript

I have lots of `*.js` files in subfolders and subsubfolders of my Node.js project which I have written recklessly, and now I'm looking for a tool that can iterate over all the files and beautify them.

I found [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) package but I'm not sure if it does what I want. Moreover, I doubt a node package is what I want. I think I need a software that I can call from the Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Vim supports formatting source code files with the command `gg=G`. `gg` is a (probably redundant) motion that jumps to the beginning of the file; `=` is the `indent` command, and the `G` motion means "execute until end of file". I know, it sounds like alien talk.

In order to execute this on many files, you can create a file and name it whatever you want, e.g. `vim-indent.txt`, inside which type the following:

```
gg=G:wq
```

with a trailing line break.

Basically this file contains a recording of keys we want to press upon running Vim. The `:wq<ENTER>` command means "write and quit", and it has to be terminated with a line-break. Without that, vim will just type the command and sit there waiting you to press enter manually.

You can then execute the script on a file like this:

```
vim -s vim-indent.txt your_file.js
```

The result is that Vim would open the file `your_file.js` and "press" all keys recorded in `vim-indent.txt`, the result of which is applying indentation, writing the file and quitting.

You can automate executing this command on an entire file tree using `find`:

```
find [path/to/your/directory] -type f -name '*.js' -exec vim -s vim-indent.txt "{}" \;
```

Note that it's highly recommended that you copy the entire directory, operate on the copy and check whether you like the result.